# How to format Y axis in an Excel chart in days, hours, minutes?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, formatting

I have an Excel chart tracking time taken to complete a task. I managed to use rows in my spreadsheet to apply custom data labels for the graph, but it doesn't match up to the Y axis of my graph.

I have tried using the 'custom' category on the Format Axis options to represent in the form:
d"d" h"h" m"m"

but as you can see below, that doesn't correspond with my graphs values.
It looks like the first horizontal measure on my graph should be for 4 days, the next for ~7, and the next one for 11 days or so.

What can I do to update my graph to accomplish this? Thank you in advance!

[image: picture of a my current graph]

I am using the following version of Excel:

*'Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2312 Build 16.0.17126.20132) 64-bit'*

Comment: If you have precise description of actual time over each column on the chart you don't need hours and minutes on the Y axis. It's enough to mark days. But you didn't show any data, so it's difficult to say what is wrong with your chart. You should use the same day measure on axis and with your columns.

Comment: I've done the exact same thing and it works fine. If you show your data we may be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** Look for discrepancies in the serial values in the series you're trying to chart.

As mentioned in the comments, without your data, it is difficult to determine exactly what the problem is.  It appears that it may be related to how Excel handles [dates](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/date-function-e36c0c8c-4104-49da-ab83-82328b832349) and [times](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/time-function-9a5aff99-8f7d-4611-845e-747d0b8d5457) v. how you're attempting to display them.

Since you didn't include your data, I created a table to show the values you presented in your example, along with their serial and formatted equivalents:

[image: data table]

So, if you just chart your values using the serial version, your chart should look something like this:

[image: serial format]

Then, just apply the custom format the data and vertical axis labels, and you'll get this:

[image: custom date/time format]